# Why a single `System.out.println(i);` gives the output twice in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm aware that "Variables" view in Eclipse can show the variables when debugging, which is not as convenient as Xcode, especially when I have a bunch of variables.

[image]

I'm trying to print Java object in debug console, similar way like in Xcode

[image]

I don't understand why a single `System.out.println(i);` gives the output twice. Could someone give me a clue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You get the output more than one time by **having `System.out.println(i);` in the *Expressions*** view.

To get the current value of `i`, either add as expression `i`, or look in the Variables view where it will be displayed by default, or in the code hover `i`, ...